# Use theme function to change the search form input type

Tags: 7, search

I use the default search block provided by Drupal.
I want to change the type of this search text box from "text" to "search." How do I do this using a theme function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the type of the search box form item with a theme function, but here's a theme friendly answer :-)

By default the *Search* input type isn't supported in Drupal 7, so you can't use any kind of `hook_form_alter` to change it out of the box.  You can do the following though to give you the ability to do what you want though:

- Download and enable the [Elements](http://www.drupal.org/project/elements) module from the awesome Dave Reid.
- Add the following to your template.php file (you can omit the size - I just put it there to make the box a bit shorter):

  ```
  function THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {  
    if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
      $form['search_block_form'] = array(
        '#type' => 'searchfield',
        '#size' => '20'
      );
    }
  }
  ```

This could also me done easily in a custom module, but I know you asked about theming specifically.

Comment: does this requires elements module?

Comment: Yes it does.  Without it there's no way to do it (as far as I'm aware).